# Corrupted Files Microsoft Office 2007 ASP.NET 1.1 and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I am working on an ASP.NET 1.1 website that stores files in the database. The website has been working great with no problems uploading and downloading any type of documents since 2001.

However, recently the customer noticed that all Microsoft Office 2007 documents `DOCX`, `XLSX`, ect are corrupted when any user try to download them.

What I have noticed is that SQL Server adds an extra byte to the `DocumentContent` (image column). Before uploading the document the content and length are fine. However, after they get stored, SQL Server adds an EXTRA Byte.... WHY?????

Many people on the internet provided a solution on how to download the file, which is great and it worked for me.

I am looking for an answer to this question... WHY DOES SQL SERVER ADD AN EXTRA BYTE TO THE IMAGE COLUMN?

It is an Asp.NET 1.1 and SQL 2000 but we just moved it to 2008 and we still have the same problem.

Comment: @marc_s If the site is really online since 2001, then it's reasonable to assume a technology level of that time as well. And if it works...

Comment: Michael, the database is SQL Server 2000 and we upgraded it to 2008 but we still have the same problem. I am going to try to change the column type right now, but I don't think it is the right idea since the column is used in so many places on the website

Comment: it is ASP.net 1.1 with VB.NET

Comment: Changing the column type should be painless and have no impact whatsoever - just use `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARBINARY(MAX)` (and test it on a test system first!!) - no change in your ASP.NET code needed.....

Comment: Can you find out **what** that byte is? What value, I mean? A `0x0` or a `0xFF` or what?

Comment: Check this site. the guy has more explanation to the problem. http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2010/02/18/why-do-excel-2007-prompt-for-repair-when-opening-a-document-stored-in-sql-server-2008-filestream-column.aspx

Comment: it is 0x0 and for changing the column. I will definitely test it on the testing server. :)

Comment: @Sami - Well if you read the link you posted - it was programming error! - not SQL Servers fault.

Comment: I Know, I am facing the same problem. However the programming fix is to fix the process of downloading the file not stoping SQL server from adding the extra byte.

Comment: Sami - well maybe you have the same programming error (defining the byte array 1 byte too big) when you are storing the file??

Comment: I subtracted 1 from the array of bytes before storing it at the database and it took off the last character from the file. So, it is not from storing the file. The link gives you the solution on how to download the file. Unfortunately I don't know where does this extra byte come from?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if your problem was the same as what I have had but in my case, I found that the problem was actually in the *writing* part, not in the reading part. For example, my original writing code was like this:

```
Dim FILE_CONTENT(len) As Byte
File.InputStream.Read(FILE_CONTENT, 0, len)
SaveFileToDatabase(FILE_NAME, CONTENT_TYPE, FILE_CONTENT)
```

When I changed the first line as the following :

```
Dim FILE_CONTENT(0 To len - 1) As Byte
```

the reading error disappeared. I just forgot that VB actually allocates N+1 bytes (O to N) by default when you dimension it without specifying the lower bound. See similar situation described here: [Uploaded Docx Files are getting corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406990/uploaded-docx-files-are-getting-corrupted) . Hope that helps.